# Vlookup similar in mysql

Tags: mysql, vlookup

Let's say I have the table ABC

```
RENT

 - 3 5 6 7 9 10

MONTH

 - Jan Mar Jan Jul Dec Feb
```

How would I go and select the MONTH corresponding to the Minimum Rent?

This is basically performing a MIN operation on the RENT but then I'm completely unaware of how to relate it to the MONTH column and extract the correspondent value.

Can you help?

Comment: Are those values individual rows in each table?

Comment: A database is not a spreadsheet... you need some way to relate the data (through primary and/or foreign keys)

Comment: select id from ABC where Sub_group = (select max(Sub_group) from ABC)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you mean a table `ABC` like this

```
MONTH RENT
----- ----
Jan   3
Mar   5
Jan   6
Jul   7
Dec   9
Feb   10
```

Then your `SELECT` to get minimum rent would be

`SELECT MONTH FROM ABC WHERE RENT=(SELECT MIN(RENT) FROM ABC);`

Answer (score 0):

When working my MySQL, you need to think about relationships in your database design. Is the month to rent relationship a 1-to-1, 1-to-many, many-to-1, many-to-many?

If you have a relationship that isn't 1-to-1, the best way to implement if is to have 3 tables. A MONTH table, a RENT table, and a table that correlates them.

- TABLE_NAME column1 column2
- MONTH pkid month
- RENT pkid amount
- MONTHLY RENT pkid fk_month fk_rent

From here, you can just do a join on the three tables using the correct columns to get the answer you want.